# Any ideas on how to number each side of a ul with items inside of it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a more complex structure which breaks down into something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/HGLNz/14/

```
<ul>
    <li class="item top"></li>
    <li class="item top-middle"></li>
    <li class="item bottom"></li>
</ul>

ul {
    background-color: blue;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 400px;
    font-size: 0;
}

ul li.item {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;;
}

li.item.top {
    top: 8px;    
}

li.item.top-middle {
    top: 108px;
}

li.item.bottom {
    top: 308px;
}
```

Basically, I render a ul, set its background and then perform a series of calculations to position items in the ul at very specific locations.

I am now attempting to number each possible location, on the left and right side, of the ul. A prototype of this would look something like:

[image]

Where the list items placed inside of the ul cover up the numbers, but locations without list items display their number visibly.

So, my question is  -- what's a good way to go about doing this? Wrapping my ul in another ul, with numbers as list items, and then cover up the numbers via z-index? Other ideas?

**UPDATE:** I am going to experiment with a solution consisting of two ULs, one nested within the other. One will be responsible for the numbering and the other for holding the content.

Comment: use CSS's :after {content:attr(index)} on the LIs, and add an index to each LI using a simple js/jQuery loop

Comment: I am not interested in numbering the green items. I am interested in having them cover up numbers indicating their positions. If I use CSS :after I would only be able to append numbers to the list items which exist.

Comment: Based on your response to Gaby's answer (which is essentially exactly what I posted), we might need some more information. As you probably know, text must be rendered by some element on the page. You can automatically number the spaces using css counters, but you'll need a set of elements that are always there. You might consider stacked ULs. The first would be static and without content (save the numbering), and the second would contain a dynamic number of list items, arranged as you'd like. Another option could be dynamically generating the markers with JS. Do either of these seem good?

Comment: You touched on something I brought up in my initial question -- stacked ULs. I just wasn't sure if there was a better way to go about doing this, but its sounding like two ULs, one for numbering, one for a dyanmic number of items, would be the appropriate answer. I'm just thinking it will be difficult to get the items to overlay ontop of the numbers when they're descendants, but maybe z-index makes it trivial.

Comment: @SeanAnderson since the numbering `ul` will be *below* (*in terms of `z-index`*) the `droppable` `ul` you will have no issue covering them up. Have you considered as an alternative a background image to the `ul` with the numbers ?

Comment: Sorry for writing that as if you hadn't considered the stacked `ul`s before, @SeanAnderson. I do see that you mentioned that possibility. Gaby, using a background image is a nice idea!

Comment: @Gaby Yeah, I have, unfortunately we currently use repeat-y on the background image to generate an effect. The ul's height is determined by customer data, so I wouldn't be able to pre-generate images without enforcing a hard limit on the supported size. I think I'm going to try the stacked UL solution along with a CSS counter and report back when I have more to say. :)

Comment: @SeanAnderson Just a nudge in the background direction. You can use dynamic backgrounds (*generated through `canvas`*). See http://jsfiddle.net/89f28/ (*and for moderns browsers that support multiple backgrounds you could use your own as well.. see http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/*)

Answer (score 3):

I'd just use CSS for this. I'm on the bus that's about to arrive, but [here's a quick JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xRgW/).

The key to this solution is CSS counters.

```
body {
  counter-reset: li-counter;
}
li {
  counter-increment: li-counter;
}
li:before,
li:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  display: block;
  content: counter(li-counter);
}
```

I'll update more with browser support, alternative solutions, etc., once I'm at home!

Edit: Gaby jumped in and wrote up basically exactly where I was going with this, so I won't elaborate on this any further. With that said, it seems like we might need more information to help you out. I wrote a bit of a long comment on the question that tries to clarify further what you might be going for.

Comment: TIL about CSS counter. Definitely interested in your full solution when you're at home. I'll keep tinkering, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you could fill the `ul` elements with the max number of `li` they support and mark the empty ones with a class you could use [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters)

This way you do not have to calculate specific positions, just mark the empty `li` as such..

```
<ul class="countable">
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item empty"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
</ul>
```

and

```
ul.countable {
    background-color: blue;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 400px;
    font-size: 0;
    counter-reset: countable-li;
}
ul.countable li.item {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position:relative;
    counter-increment:countable-li;
}
ul.countable li.empty{
    background-color:blue;
}
ul.countable li.empty:after,
ul.countable li.empty:before{
    content: counter(countable-li);
    font-family:courier;
    color:white;
    line-height:12px;
    font-size:12px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    right:5px;
    margin-top:-6px;
}
ul.countable li.empty:before{
    right:auto;
    left:5px;
}
ul.countable li:before,
ul.countable li:after{
    content:none;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/uVRwh/

Comment: This is definitely something I have considered, played with and then backed out of, thinking it was too messy and that there had to be something simpler. I'll definitely pursue this route if there's nothing else though, thanks. :)

Comment: @SeanAnderson, if you can post some info about your specific case and what you try to accomplish we may be able to suggest a more specific route ..

Comment: Well, the list items inside of the ul implement jQuery draggable and the ul implements droppable. The ul itself represents a "rack" of equipment and each li represents a piece of equipment which can be dragged around inside of the rack. I would like to indicate free slots by numbering the ul at calculated intervals. An overlay would work best because it wouldn't mess with my drag-and-drop, but using 'dummy' li's makes the numbering simple. So I'm trying to assess options before going down a path that makes things unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use he counter reset property

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/BtcrG/2/)

```
    body {
  counter-reset: my-awesome-counter;
}
li {
  counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
}

li:before {
  content: counter(my-awesome-counter);
    position:absolute;
    left:.5em;
    color:white;
}
li:after {
  content: counter(my-awesome-counter);
    position:absolute;
    right:.5em;
    color:white;
}

ul {
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 400px;
}

li {
    position:relative;
}
```